# Understand populate in mongoose

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, schema

I have collections named Book and Author. A book can be written by a few authors. So the collections look like this:

```
Book: {
id: objectId,
name: string,
price: number,
authors: [objectId]
}

Author: {
id: objectId,
nameL string
}
```

The author's field of Book collection is an array of author objectId.
When I want to get some books and their authors, I will get the author objectId array. Then, for each objectId element, I will get the author.
Another way to do this is using "populate". But I don't know is this way like "join" in a relational database? Does it have better performance than the first way?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are going to have some book data with each authors. Instead of using `populate` (because `populate` is in mongoose), I have using `$lookup` in mongodb and it's more like join in relational database also. Here are the documentation

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#use-lookup-with-an-array

Comment: Is ```$lookup``` faster than ```populate```?

Comment: I have not try to compare in between, but I read this post on [medium](https://medium.com/cameoeng/mongodb-lookups-and-populates-an-unexpected-journey-940e08e36a94) as my answer reference. I think you could do the same if you need some exact performance